# Using SUBSTRING with a column name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've been trying this all morning and can't find what I'm doing wrong. I have a string, 'XXYY0000' and I need the XX and YY seperatly.

So this works and gets the XX values:

```
SELECT LEFT(l.LOAN_MATURITY, 2)
FROM LOAN As l
```

But why is this not working when I need to get the YY values?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(l.LOAN_MATURITY, 3, 2)
FROM LOAN As l
```

I researched and it should give the same output as the `MID()` function, but it gives me this error.

> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Argument data type numeric is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.

Why is the data type important for the `SUBSTRING` function but not the `LEFT` function?

Comment: Why it doesn't work I can't tell but it works when you cast the numeric to varchar:  SELECT SUBSTRING(cast(l.LOAN_MATURITY as varchar), 3, 2) FROM LOAN As l

Comment: What data type *is* `l.LOAN_MATURITY`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`LEFT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx)**:

> LEFT ( character_expression , integer_expression )
>
> character_expression
>
> Is an expression of character or binary data. character_expression can be a constant, variable, or column. **character_expression can be of
>   any data type, except text or ntext, that can be implicitly converted
>   to varchar or nvarchar**. Otherwise, use the CAST function to explicitly
>   convert character_expression.

**[`SUBSTRING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)**:

> SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )
>
> expression
>
> Is a character, binary, text, ntext, or image expression.

With `LEFT` there is implicit `CAST`, with `SUBSTRING` not. You need to `CAST` it manually:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(l.LOAN_MATURITY AS VARCHAR(100)), 3, 2)
FROM LOAN As l
```